# use ansible-runner as Python module Interface to Ansible error: RunnerConfig' object has no attribute 'command'

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-runner

I use ansible 2.9.13 and ansible-runner 1.4.6

Below is my Python code:

```
from ansible_runner import Runner, RunnerConfig

f = open('/home/george/dev/beeops/ansible_private/keyfile', 'r')
key = f.read()
rc = RunnerConfig(private_data_dir='/home/george/dev/beeops/ansible_private',
                  playbook='test.yml',
                  inventory='127.0.0.1',
                  ssh_key=key,)
r = Runner(config=rc)
r.run()
```

An error occurred while I was executing this code，

```py
  File "/home/george/venv/bops/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible_runner/runner.py", line 114, in run
    command = self.config.command
AttributeError: 'RunnerConfig' object has no attribute 'command'
```

Can someone help me see what the problem is?
Thanks to all the friends who responded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the direct runner execution is not [fully documented](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner/blob/054d26b72fabc86ef8f53b1a39feb61591eb7b87/ansible_runner/runner_config.py#L71). When reading the [code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner/blob/054d26b72fabc86ef8f53b1a39feb61591eb7b87/ansible_runner/interface.py#L74), a call to `rc.prepare()` should be done before calling `r.run()`.

```
from ansible_runner import Runner, RunnerConfig

f = open('/home/george/dev/beeops/ansible_private/keyfile', 'r')
key = f.read()
rc = RunnerConfig(private_data_dir='/home/george/dev/beeops/ansible_private',
                  playbook='test.yml',
                  inventory='127.0.0.1',
                  ssh_key=key,)
rc.prepare()
r = Runner(config=rc)
r.run()
```

All this is done for you when using the [helper interfaces](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_interface.html#using-runner-as-a-python-module-interface-to-ansible) as documented.